# How to disable Visual Studio macro "tip" balloon?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, tweak

Whenever I use a macro in Visual Studio I get an annoying tip balloon in the system tray and an accompanying "pop" sound. It says:

> Visual Studio .NET macros
>
> To stop the macro from running, double-click the spinning cassette.
>   Click here to not show this balloon again.

I have trouble clicking the balloon because my macro runs so quickly.

Is this controllable by some dialog box option?

(I found someone else asking this question on [some other site](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VisualStudio/microsoft.public.vsnet.ide/2005-11/msg00267.html) but it's not answered there. I give credit here because I've copied and pasted some pieces from there.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will disable the pop up:

For Visual Studio 2008:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0

DWORD DontShowMacrosBalloon=6
```

For Visual Studio 2010 (the DWORD won't be there by default, use `New | DWORD value` to create it):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

DWORD DontShowMacrosBalloon=6
```

Delete the same key to re-enable it.

Comment: Thanks! Anything special about 6 though? I'm guessing it just has to be nonzero. When I look after disabling it as described below, it's set to 1. And of course 8.0 could be something different... Penticton, eh? Risqué place for a webcam. ;-)

Comment: Same for Visual Studio 2010, only the path is 10.0, not 8.0.   The DWORD doesn't exist by default, create a (32-bit) DWORD using regedit.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found a way to make the balloon clickable, and clicking it does indeed stop it from popping up again. (On the other site I referenced in the original question the question asker claims that this is not the case. Though he was in VS2005 and I'm using VS2008.)

Anyway, I inserted a pause line in the macro so it would run for long enough for me to click the balloon:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

It would still be nice to know if there's a dialog somewhere for turning this back on, in case I have a crazy change of heart.